# How to strip binary characters from a file?

Tags: linux, text, ascii

I've got a file that contains lines that look like this in `vim`:

   `^[[0;32msalt-2016.3.2-1.el6.noarch^[[0;0m^M`

which look like this in `more`:

   `salt-2016.3.2-1.el6.noarch`

I would like to produce a copy of this file that only contains the displayed characters as more shows them. I tried piping it through `dos2unix` but it refuses to do anything, complaining that "dos2unix: Binary symbol 0x1B found at line 2".

Probably I could achieve what I want with some sed statements, but I'm wondering whether there is a linux/unix utility that will take output from more or cat and produce a file that contains only the whitespace and text as displayed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's something called [ansifilter](http://www.andre-simon.de/doku/ansifilter/en/ansifilter.php) which does exactly this. I tested it out on my file and it works.